# Debugger Unexpectedly Detaches

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have an ASP.Net MVC project that I have been working on for many months without incident.  Since yesterday, the VS 2012 debugger consistently detaches from the project after it has been running for 2-3 minutes.  So far, I cannot find any specific event that might trigger the detach.

I have not recently updated VS 2012 or any 3rd party libraries.

I can attach to the project again using Debug / Attach to Process.  I have not observed the debugger detaching again after manually re-attaching.

When running a different, console program in the debugger I do not observe the same behavior.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?